# If $\lim_{x \to a}(f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x \to a}(f(x)g(x))=0$ then $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Is the following true?

> If $\lim_{x \to a}(f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x \to a}(f(x)g(x))=0$ then $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$

**My attempt:**

Couldn't come up with a counter example. Also, solving the system

$\begin{cases} f+g=s \\fg=p \end{cases}$

for $f,g$ gives

$$\left\{\left\{f\to \frac{1}{2} \left(s-\sqrt{s^2-4 p}\right),g\to \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{s^2-4 p}+s\right)\right\},\left\{f\to \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{s^2-4 p}+s\right),g\to \frac{1}{2} \left(s-\sqrt{s^2-4 p}\right)\right\}\right\} $$

which seems to suggest that the limits of $f$ and $g$ at $a$ are equal. However, I'm not certain whether the square roots exist in a neighbourhood of $a$, and even if they do, I can't formulate a complete proof.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider $(f-g)^2=(f+g)^2-4fg$